# Can we use ASP.NET MVC 4's mobile switching on .net 4.0 host?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My site is bin deployed to DiscountASP.net. I was going to attempt to make an m.domain mobile site separate, but it appears they don't support that as cleanly as I had hoped (they will setup a wildcard subdomain pointer, and then in code we support our own subdomains... not really what I had in mind).

DiscountASP, at this time, is running .net 4.0. Would I be able to use the ASP.NET MVC 4 mobile features? Primarily the layout switching (viewName.mobile.cshtml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  MVC 4 detects mobile browsers based on the user agent, so you should be able to just create the mobile views, and point the mobile browsers to your main site to get mobile views.

Comment: So the installed .net framework on the server doesn't matter? All the magic happens in the bin deployed assemblies?

Comment: You might want to include 51degrees.mobi (NuGet package).  It is kept more up to date with all the current mobile devices out there.